# Installing lapack95 in ubuntu

Tags: libraries

I am trying to install lapack95(https://www.netlib.org/lapack95/lapack95.tgz) library in my system. This is giving an error "f95: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-ieee=full’
".
What is the solution and how can I install it? I tried to proceed exactly according to the way described in README. By navingating to the SRC folder, I ran make, and the error was encountered.

Comment: You haven't given many details, we don't know your OS/release details, nor can we see the full messages of what you are trying to execute (usually commands or script where examining script plus output from execution provide the clearest clues).

Comment: Likely the `f95` on your system is actually gfortran, whereas the software you are trying to build expects NAG f95. See if the makefile modifications suggested here help: [Building common software packages with gfortran](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GfortranBuild)

Answer (score 1):

[You need to edit the make.inc](https://cyber.dabamos.de/programming/modernfortran/lapack.html%3Cbr/%3E)

On Ubuntu:

wget https://www.netlib.org/lapack95/lapack95.tgz 
tar xfvz lapack95.tgz 
cd LAPACK95 
nano make.inc  
change the following lines and save make.inc 
FC    = gfortran -ffree-form 
FC1   = gfortran -ffixed-form 
OPTS0 = 
save the file 
cd SRC/ 
make single_double_complex_dcomplex